# Why Java 8 Stream interface does not have min() no-parameter version?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

`java.util.stream.Stream` interface has two versions of `sorted` method – `sorted()` which sorts elements in natural order and `sorted(Comparator)`. Why `min()` method was not introduced to `Stream` interface, which would return minimal element from natural-ordering point of view?

Comment: The answers already given are helpful, but don't quite get to the main point. So, there are 2 versions of `sorted` method – `sorted()` and  `sorted(Comparator)`. It seems to me a little inconsistent that `min()` was not introduced together with `min(Comparator)` when there are corresponding versions of `sorted`. There should be some reason.

Comment: `Stream.sorted()` was a mistake. There should be only `Stream.sorted(Comparator)`.

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov I thought so too, but I cant find any mailing lists discussions on this

Comment: @Eugene They just have no courage to acknowledge that :)

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov haha! I doubt it, waiting for Stuart Marks here hopefully

Answer (score 13):

It should be clear that for `min`, `max`, and `sorted`, adding a method to `Stream` that does not require a comparator introduces a way to lose the generic type safety. The reason is that the current version of the Java language does not support restricting methods to instances of a specific parameterization, i.e. limit them to streams of comparable elements.

So the question could be the other way round, *why has this potential break of the type safety been allowed with `sorted()`*?

I can’t look into the developers mind, but one interesting point is that sorting has been treated specially for a long time now. With the introduction of Generics, it became possible to enforce that sorting without a `Comparator` can only be attempted for collections or arrays with comparable elements. However, especially when implementing generic collections, developers might face the fact that arrays can’t be created with a generic element type. There might be other scenarios, where a developer encounters an array or collection of a formally non-comparable type while the contained elements are comparable for sure. As said, I can’t look into the developers mind to say, which scenarios were considered.

But

- [`Arrays.sort(Object[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-java.lang.Object:A-) does not enforce the array type to be a subtype of `Comparable`. Even if it did,
- [`sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-) specifies that a `null` comparator implies “natural order”, which allows requesting natural order for any type
- [`Collections.sort(List<T> list)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-) requires a comparable element type, *but*
- [`Collections.sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-) again specifies that a `null` comparator implies “natural order”, so there’s still an easy way to undermine the type system. Since the “`null` means natural” rule [was already specified before Generics existed](http://web.archive.org/web/20050303003346/http://java.sun.com:80/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)), it had to be kept for compatibility.

But it’s not just all about backwards compatibility. [`List.sort(Comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-), introduced in Java 8, is also specified as accepting `null` as argument for “natural order”, so now we have another scenario, where an implementer might have to sort data without a compile-time type that guarantees comparable elements.

So when it comes to sorting, there are already lots of opportunities to dodge the type system. But [`Stream.sorted(Comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted-java.util.Comparator-) is the only sort method not accepting a `null` comparator. So sorting by natural order without specifying `Comparator.naturalOrder()` is only possible using `sorted()` without arguments. By the way, having an already sorted input with a `null` comparator and requesting `sorted()` without comparator is the only situation where the Stream implementation will detect that sorting isn’t necessary, i.e. it doesn’t compare comparators and doesn’t check for `Comparator.naturalOrder()`.

Generally, the type safety of comparators is astonishing weak. E.g. [`Collections.reverseOrder()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder--) returns a comparator of arbitrary type, not demanding the type to be comparable. So instead of `min()`, you could use `max(Collections.reverseOrder())` to request the minimum, regardless of the stream’s formal type. Or use `Collections.reverseOrder(Collections.reverseOrder())` to get the equivalent of `Comparator.naturalOrder()` for an arbitrary type. Likewise, [`Collator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html) implements `Comparator<Object>`, for whatever reason, despite it can only compare `String`s.

Comment: what do you mean by `limit them to streams of comparable elements`? A way of saying that unless there is a type `T extends Comparable...`, you can't have the visibility (access) a method `max` let's say?

Comment: @Eugene: yes, a hypothetical way to say “this method can only be invoked, if the target is assignable to `Stream<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`”. There is already a syntax that allows to add annotations to `this`’s type, so on the syntax side, the change wouldn’t be so big. But semantically, it would be a big step.

Answer (score 5):

I'd assume that would just pollute the API. one could say *"why is there no max parameterless version"*, *"why is there no CharStream"* and it could on and on in terms of the things that could be made available but were decided best not to.

having a parameterless min method over this:

```
someList.stream().min(Comparator.naturalOrder());
```

would be no different.

therefore it's best to just create a *reusable* method rather than polluting the API with all the possible things.

Comment: The possible pollution is a good point, but then parameter-less `sorted()` would not have been introduced.

Answer (score 3):

I think min() only allows the signature that accepts a Comparator because the Stream could be of any type, even a type created by you. In such case it would be impossible to rely on a natural order, as the class you've created, can't have a natural order until you specify it.

If, insteam of the class Stream you use, IntStream, you'll see that a min() method with no arguments is defined. This does what you want. It is the following:

```
public static void main (String... args){
        IntStream s=IntStream.of(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
        System.out.println(s.min().getAsInt());
    }
```

Comment: Hmmm... Good point, but `sorted()` also also requires the elements to implement `Comparable` but it still has been introduced to the interface.

Comment: I hear you. i'm starting to getting curious too about this thing. Another clue to find this out, maybe, is that sorted is an intermediate operation, whereas min/max aren't. But i can't actually think of how this might help

Answer (score 3):

[Comparator.naturalOrder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#naturalOrder--) serves this purpose. Its existence (or custom implementations thereof) allows other classes to remain simpler because they don't have to implement special codepaths for null-values in Comparator fields.

Its type will also force the stream's T to implement Comparable.

Comment: Yes, `Comparator.naturalOrder()` helps in this case without doubt, but still it does not quite answer the question (see comment to main question).