# Why is Stream.sorted not type-safe in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, comparable

This is from the Stream interface from Oracle's implementation of JDK 8:

```
public interface Stream<T> extends BaseStream<T, Stream<T>> {
    Stream<T> sorted();
}
```

and it is very easy to blow this up at run time and no warning will be generated at compile time. Here is an example:

```
class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Arrays.asList(new Foo(), new Foo()).stream().sorted().forEach(f -> {});
    }
}
```

which will compile just fine but will throw an exception at run time:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Foo cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
```

What could be the reason that the `sorted` method was not defined where the compiler could actually catch such problems? Maybe I am wrong but isn't it this simple:

```
interface Stream<T> {
    <C extends Comparable<T>> void sorted(C c);
}
```

?

Obviously the guys implementing this (who are light years ahead of me as far as programming and engineering is considered) must have a very good reason that I am unable to see, but what is that reason?

Comment: You mean `Comparator`? There's already an [overload](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted-java.util.Comparator-) for that. Not sure why you need `C` though.

Comment: @shmosel What I am trying to ask is: Why is Java not expecting a type that is of T and extends Comparable in `Stream.sorted`..

Comment: It's not possible to do that.

Comment: @shmosel Due to the nature of functional programming? I am just trying to learn, not to fight, but can you help me understand why my suggestion would not work? The one with `C extends .. sorted(C c)`?

Comment: Due to the nature of generics. The whole point of generics is that you're implementing *generic* functionality, which precludes type-specific logic. Your sample code doesn't make any sense. I think you're trying to redefine `T` (which isn't possible), but you're actually just defining a type for a useless argument.

Comment: In your `sorted` example you're requiring an argument of type `? extends Comparable`. Where is this argument going to come from?

Comment: @shomsel I am not trying to redefine `T`, I am just trying to say: The argument you pass to `sorted`  must of type `T` and must extend `Comparable`. I guess I must refresh my Generics...  So there is no way to declare this in Java?

Comment: but `sorted` does not take any arguments as input - where are you going to take this argument from?

Comment: @Eugene Ah, yes.. Obviously.. I guess I am too tired.. But maybe it could accept a Class<C> then.. To make it type safe.. But that is another story.. Can you update your answer, I will mark it as correct? This comment of yours makes much more sense then your current answer.

Comment: There's no guarantee that `Class<C>` is assignable from `Class<T>`.

Comment: This problem predates java 8 btw

Comment: well I did update it, but I don't see a real value in it - as said, this would be either impossible to implement, or it would mean that certain operations could only be called in some order, like a theoretical `mapToComprable` and only after that `sorted`, but that would be a mess

Comment: In C++ you'd have `Stream<T>` **not have** the member `Stream<T> sorted()` if `T` did not satisfy `T extends Comparable<? super T>`, but that's a major change to how Java does things. Perhaps Java 11 can have a `requires` qualifier on methods to suppress them based on type bounds.

Comment: @Caleth vey interesting point, but if java would ever do that - I guess that would be done *somehow* via annotations

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Essentially, you're asking if there's a way to tell the compiler, "*hey, this one method requires the type parameter match more specific bounds than defined at the class level*". This is not possible in Java. Such a feature may be useful but I'd also expect confusing and/or complicated.

There's also no way to make `Stream.sorted()` type-safe with how generics is currently implemented; not if you want to avoid requiring a `Comparator`. For instance, you were proposing something like:

```
public interface Stream<T> {

    <C extends Comparable<? super T>> Stream<T> sorted(Class<C> clazz);

} // other Stream methods omitted for brevity
```

Unfortunately, there's no guarantee that `Class<C>` is assignable from `Class<T>`. Consider the following hierarchy:

```
public class Foo implements Comparable<Foo> { /* implementation */ }

public class Bar extends Foo {}

public class Qux extends Foo {}
```

You can now have a `Stream` of `Bar` elements but try to sort it as if it was a `Stream` of `Qux` elements.

```
Stream<Bar> stream = barCollection.stream().sorted(Qux.class);
```

Since both `Bar` and `Qux` match `Comparable<? super Foo>` there is no compile-time error and thus no type-safety is added. Also, the implication of requiring a `Class` argument is that it'll be used for casting. At runtime this can, as shown above, still result in `ClassCastException`s. If the `Class` *isn't* used for casting then the argument is completely useless; I'd even consider it harmful.

The next logical step is to try and require `C` extend `T` as well as `Comparable<? super T>`. For example:

```
<C extends T & Comparable<? super T>> Stream<T> sorted(Class<C> clazz);
```

This is also not possible in Java and results in a compilation error: "type parameter cannot be followed by other bounds". Even if this were possible, I don't think it'd solve everything (if anything at all).

---

*Some related notes.*

Regarding `Stream.sorted(Comparator)`: It isn't the `Stream` that makes this method type-safe, it's the `Comparator`. The `Comparator` ensures the elements can be compared. To illustrate, the type-safe way to sort a `Stream` by the elements' natural order is:

```
Stream<String> stream = stringCollection.stream().sorted(Comparator.naturalOrder());
```

This is type-safe because `naturalOrder()` requires its type parameter extend `Comparable`. If the generic type of the `Stream` did not extend `Comparable` then the bounds wouldn't match, resulting in a compilation error. But again, it's the `Comparator` that requires the elements be `Comparable`<sup>*</sup> while the `Stream` simply doesn't care.

So the question becomes, why did the developers include a no-argument `sorted` method for `Stream` in the first place? It appears to be for historical reasons and is explained in [an answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47867848/2711488) by Holger.

---

<sup>* The `Comparator` requires the elements be `Comparable` in this case. In general, a `Comparator` is obviously capable of handling any type it's defined to.</sup>

Answer (score 19):

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted()) for `Stream#sorted` explains it perfectly:

> Returns a stream consisting of the elements of this stream, sorted according to natural order. If the elements of this stream are not Comparable, a java.lang.ClassCastException may be thrown when the terminal operation is executed.

You're using the overloaded method that accepts no arguments (not the one that accepts a `Comparator`), and `Foo` does not implement `Comparable`.

If you're asking why the method doesn't throw a compiler error if the contents of the `Stream` do not implement `Comparable`, it would be because `T` is not forced to extend `Comparable`, and `T` cannot be changed without a call to `Stream#map`; it seems to only be a convenience method so no explicit `Comparator` needs to be provided when the elements already implement `Comparable`.

For it to be type-safe, `T` would have to extend `Comparable`, but that would be ridiculous, as it would prevent a stream from containing any objects that aren't `Comparable`.

Comment: `it would be because T is not forced to extend Comparable` I know, but why does sorted accept a T but not something like what I suggest at the end of my question?

Comment: There's already an overloaded `Stream#sorted` method that accepts a `Comparator`. It accepting a `Comparable` wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: I guess the point you are trying to make is that since `sorted` is part of the Stream class (which has type parameter `T`) `T` should not implement `Comparable` as that will force *all* types using the stream pipeline to implement Comparable.

Comment: @user7 Exactly :) which is why the documentation states "sorted according to natural order". Objects that don't implement `Comparable` don't have a natural order.

Comment: @user7 Yes, obviously that would be a disaster.. But can we not just define a method parameters type to be of generic type of the interface AND restrict it to also something else? (That is what I tried in the last code snipped in my question, at least I tried to..)

Comment: @KorayTugay I don't believe something like that is possible unless you want to create another `Stream` implementation (that only accepts `Comparable` elements) and have this `Stream` map to it, but that's overkill.

Comment: @JacobG. actually, restricting the receiver’s type via method parameter is possible and such a method even exist, i.e. `sorted(Comparator.naturalOrder())` can only be invoked on a stream, if its elements are comparable. It was a deliberate decision to add another `sorted()` method without parameters.

Answer (score 16):

How would you implement that? `sorted` is a intermediate operation (can be called anywhere between other intermediate operations), meaning you can start with a stream that is not Comparable, but call `sorted` on one that *is* `Comparable`:

```
Arrays.asList(new Foo(), new Foo())
      .stream()
      .map(Foo::getName) // name is a String for example
      .sorted()
      .forEach(f -> {});
```

The thing that you are proposing takes an argument as input, but `Stream::sorted` does not, so you can't do that. The overload version accepts a `Comparator` - meaning you can sort something by a property, but still return `Stream<T>`. I think that this is quite easy to understand if you would try to write your minimal skeleton of a Stream interface/implementation.

Comment: Well `sorted` in this example knows the type again, that is a Stream<String>, isn 't it?

Comment: Well, the alternative would be not to have a zero-arg `sorted()` method, thus requiring you to use `sorted(Comparator.naturalOrder())` instead. That would be type safe. It’s a trade off. Compare with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47867848/2711488) discussing the special treatment of sorting operations.

Comment: @Holger I wish you provided an answer, what you share in comments is very valuable but might be overlooked.

Comment: @Holger good point, and now that you have said this explicitly I don't really understand why plain `sorted` was provided to begin with