# Java 8 Streams:Why does mapToInt needs the Integer::parseInt as a parameter?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to understand something following the next example:

```
    Stream.of("a1", "a2", "a3")
            .map(s -> s.substring(1))
            .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
            .max()

     . (etc.)
```

Why does mapToInt needs the

```
    Integer::parseInt
```

as a parameter? Shouldn't it be implicit for it? Isn't this parameter redundant?

Comment: You could provide any method that returns an `int` or `Integer`, I guess, but if you are streaming an array of `String`s, then `Integer.parseInt` seems the best option...

Comment: The `Stream#mapToInt` method takes an `IntFunction` to map an _arbitrary type_ (not just `String`) to an `int`. The method also returns an `IntStream` which is a stream specialized for `int`. Why do you think this `IntFunction` argument could be implicit?

Comment: What if you have `List<Car>` where each car has `car.getAmountOfDors()` and you want to create `int[] dors`? How would you write stream for it? What should be placed in `???` to make `int[] dors = cars.stream().???.toArray();` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to differentiate between what calling [`Stream#mapToInt(ToIntFunction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToInt(java.util.function.ToIntFunction)) does and what the [`ToIntFunction`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/ToIntFunction.html) argument does.

- The call to `mapToInt` is **what** the stream is going to do (i.e. map the elements to an `int`).
- The `ToIntFunction` argument is **how** the stream is going to map each element to an `int`.

---

Could they have included a no-arg `mapToInt` method that implicitly parses `String`s to `int`s? Yes, but [look at how well that works for `Stream#sorted()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53219523/6395627)—and that situation is nowhere near as arbitrary or ambiguous as a no-arg `mapToInt` method.

The no-arg `sorted` method assumes the elements are `Comparable` which is a fundamental, standardized and wide-spread interface in Java—any class can implement the interface (whereas there's only one class that can be a `String`). Thus while the method is not type-safe it can be argued the use-case is common enough to justify its existence.

However, a no-arg `mapToInt` method that assumes the elements are `String`s and parses their content to an `int` is a highly specific use-case. Why would such a generic API offer such a specific operation? It'd be an entirely arbitrary decision with no reasonable justification. For instance, why not map each `String` to its `length` instead? And why is `String` being handled specially but not some other type(s)? Hence the method accepts a `ToIntFunction` argument that describes *how* to map the elements to an `int` on a case-by-case basis.

---

It may help to note that `Integer::parseInt` is a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html), which is shorthand for a trivial [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html). Both are an implementation of a [functional interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.8) which is less verbose option than using an [anonymous class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html). In other words, you're creating a new `ToIntFunction` instance and passing it as an argument.

All of the following are functionally equivalent:

```
// method reference
stream.mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)

// lambda expression
stream.mapToInt((String value) -> Integer.parseInt(value)) // explicit parameter types
stream.mapToInt(value -> Integer.parseInt(value))          // implicit parameter types

// anonymous class
stream.mapToInt(new ToIntFunction<>() {

    @Override
    public int applyAsInt(String value) {
        return Integer.parseInt(value);
    }

})
```

Where `stream` is a `Stream<String>`.

Answer (score 1):

`substring` returns a string not an integer.
`mapToInt` converts the stream of objects (in this case Strings) to an `IntStream` of int primitives. However it doesn't know how to do the mapping, you need to provide it a function, which in your case is `parseInt`.

Comment: No, `parseInt` doesn't return an `Integer` object; `valueOf` does. `parseInt` returns a primitive `int`.

Answer (score 1):

the operations you are doing are like:

```
Stream.of("a1", "a2", "a3")           //step1
        .map(s -> s.substring(1))     //step2
        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)  //step3
        .max()
```

you define a stream of strings (in step1), then you take eauch of them an discard the 1 char on it leaving a stream of "1", "2"and "3", (step2) but note that those are still string objects...
then you convert that into integers therefore you need to give to the 'mapToInt' a "function" that takes a string as parameter and returns an integer (step3)

and that is defined in the Integer class:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)

you can for sure write and pass your own function... but why to reinvent the wheel? :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not redundant. You need to say how convert (say) the string "1" to the integer 1.

(I guess you could argue that a no-argument `mapToLong` method would be convenient, but the designers didn't include one in the API.)

---

I guess you could also be asking why go to the bother of the explicit integer conversion.

If you try to apply `Stream::max` to a stream of numbers-represented-as-strings, you will get the lexically largest value, not the numerically largest value. For example "9" is larger than "11".

Note that the `Stream::max` method does not have an overload with no arguments.  You would need to provide a comparator; e.g.

```
Stream.of("a1", "a2", "a3")
    .map(s -> s.substring(1))
    .max(compareAsIntegers)
```

where

```
Comparator<String> compareAsIntegers = new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare (String s1, String s2) {
        return Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(s1),
                               Integer.parseInt(s2));
    }
}
```

Comment: You can simply use `Comparator.comparingInt(Integer::parseInt)` as `Comparator`. But I don't get what that hypothetical “no-argument `mapToLong` method” should do.

Answer (score 0):

Well actually, after reading the kind answers here I understood 
1. That my question was not clear enough.
2. The answer...

So,

1. What I really meant was - isn't passing the Integer::parseInt as an argument to mapToInt redundant? Because I felt the mapToInt describes exactly the purpose of the method - mapping an object to int, And adding the parseInt is needless because it actually the same - parse an object to int...
2. But then I tried to pass also Integer:valueOf and it was accepted as well - so I understood that there are couple of options to pass to mapToInt, and that answered my question...

Comment: Thanks! I'll be joyful to accept your comments as an answer if you'd like to!

Comment: `Integer::valueOf` is a bad example as it still does the same as `Integer::parseInt`, but with needless boxing and unboxing in this context. Consider examples like `String::length` which converts a `String` to an `int` doing something entirely different. And the generic class `Stream` does not have a builtin way of converting its elements to `int` by assuming that they were always `String` instances...

Answer (score 0):

1)mapToInt function's main purpose is to convert current stream to Intstream, over which other Integer operations can be performed like sum,Min,max etc.

2. It's generics you can never predict what will be the input, in your case it is String, it might be double ,long or Something else.
   It has been left to Developers to take care of explicit cast.
3. You can write your own function, here in this case it is function<T,int>   which is nothing but the ToIntFunction taken as an argument of mapToInt func.
   You can rewrite your own functional interface like function<String, int> , but here also u need to do parseInt inside of function applyAsInt, but this will be a one time job that you can reuse while making certain other similar calls.